# C# single character date format

Tags: c#, datetime, tostring

I'm trying to get only the day, or the hour from a DateTime object. Though, I'm facing the problem that single-character dateformat strings are not accepted, because some of them have a special meaning.

The following throws a System.FormatException:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("H")
```

I could get around this restriction by adding any character, and removing it with a substring. Though this seems kind of arbitrary:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(" H").Substring(1)
```

Isn't there a better way of getting these single character date formats to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `%` to define a custom format as specified in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

```cs
//Example
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("%H"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get just the hour of your DateTime Object you can get that with `.Hour;`

**Example:**

```cs
// Create Datetime object
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

// Get Hour from DateTime object
int hour = dateTime.Hour;
```

Comment: Though correct, this doesn't entirely fit my usecase, since the dateformats are provided as a string by the user.